# Where is term "uswa e hassna" used in quran?

Tags: quran, reference-request, quran-translation, uloom-al-quran

In Quran,I am trying to search Which verses and sura mention the term"uswa e hassna"
Please kindly guide me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Arabic Term:

> أُسْوَةٌ حَسَنَةٌ
>    <sub>Transliteration</sub>
>   Uswatun hassanatun *or* Oswatun hassanatun

refers to a good or even excellent example.
As

> أُسْوَة Uswah

refers to example, model or pattern.
While

> حَسَن hassan

refers to everything that is good, fine, charming, beautiful etc.

And it appears in the qur'an three times once in the context of our messenger Muhammad () in surat al-Ahzaab :

> There has certainly been for you in the Messenger of Allah an **excellent pattern** for anyone whose hope is in Allah and the Last Day and [who] remembers Allah often. ([33:21](https://legacy.quran.com/33/21))

And twice in surat al-Mumtahanah in the context of Ibraheem ():

> There has already been for you an **excellent pattern** in Abraham and those with him, when they said to their people, "Indeed, we are disassociated from you and from whatever you worship other than Allah . We have denied you, and there has appeared between us and you animosity and hatred forever until you believe in Allah alone" except for the saying of Abraham to his father, "I will surely ask forgiveness for you, but I have not [power to do] for you anything against Allah . Our Lord, upon You we have relied, and to You we have returned, and to You is the destination. ([60:4](https://legacy.quran.com/60/4))

and

> There has certainly been for you in them an **excellent pattern** for anyone whose hope is in Allah and the Last Day. And whoever turns away - then indeed, Allah is the Free of need, the Praiseworthy. ([60:6](https://legacy.quran.com/60/6))

Answer (score 3):

There is no "Uswa e hassna".

The phrase is **oswatun hasanatun** **أُسْوَةٌ حَسَنَةٌ** and it is used in the Holy Quran in three locations [33:21](https://quran.com/33/21) ,
[60:4](https://quran.com/60/4)  and
[60:6](https://quran.com/60/6).

Answer (score 1):

This term is used in `Surah Al-Mumtahanah` Verse `4`

[image]

English Translation:

> There has already been for you an excellent pattern in Abraham and those with him, when they said to their people, "Indeed, we are disassociated from you and from whatever you worship other than Allah . We have denied you, and there has appeared between us and you animosity and hatred forever until you believe in Allah alone" except for the saying of Abraham to his father, "I will surely ask forgiveness for you, but I have not [power to do] for you anything against Allah . Our Lord, upon You we have relied, and to You we have returned, and to You is the destination.

and Our Prophet Mohammed (Peace be Upon him) mentioned as uswa e hasnait in Surah-Ahzab verse (21)
you may check here too

https://www.searchtruth.com/chapter_display_all.php?chapter=33&from_verse=21&to_verse=21&translation_setting=1&show_transliteration=1&show_yusufali=1&show_shakir=1&show_pickthal=1&show_mkhan=1&show_saheeh=1&show_urdu=1

Comment: It mentions Prophet Ibrahim (Peace be Upon him) but at which  place (sura verses ) our Prophet Mohammed (Peace be Upon him) mentioned as uswa e hasna

Comment: Our Prophet Mohammed (Peace be Upon him) mentioned as uswa e hasnait  in Surah-Ahzab

Comment: verse number 21; you may check  too

Comment: Please kindly also include this refrence of sura ahzaab  it in your answer so i may accept your

Comment: sure you may check now

Comment: Jazak Allah dear

Comment: sorry for i unaccepted your answer as it lacked bit formatting as compared to the answer given by @Medi1saif